# Session deletion in Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

How do I delete all session variables at once if they are not in Array?

PS I set them this way:

```
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('PayPalTransaction.hash', $request->getParameter('hash'));
```

Regards,
Roman

Comment: Need to delete session in the task by namespace. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `sfUser` class (which you get with `$this->getUser()`), keeps all it's attributes in a `sfNamespacedParameterHolder`. So the `setAttribute()` function on `sfUser` if merely a proxy to the `sfNamespacedParameterHolder::setAttribute()`. You can get the reference to this holder with `sfUser::getAttributeHolder()`.

The `sfNamespacedParameterHolder` also has a function `clear()`, which clears all attributes.

So to clear all attributes, use:
`$this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->clear()`.

(Please note that you will still be authenticated (e.g. logged in) when you clear the attribute holder).

Comment: Grad,
if I store session in Array, I lose the ability of direct access, isn't it? E.g. I cannot easily change value or just use getAttribute() to refer to certain element...

Comment: Ehm? Could you clarify what you're trying to do? (Or open a new question, so everyone can answer)

Answer (score 8):

Another way if you want to remove just one session variable not all of them is to use the following code

```
$this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->remove('att_name');
```

Again this will only remove one not all ... to clear all use the previous code by Grad

Answer (score 7):

To remove all attributes of a namespace :

```
$this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->removeNamespace('yournamespace');
```